# NHibernate ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: session, nhibernate, task

I recently ran into an instance where I wanted to hit the database from a Task I have running periodically within a web application. I refactored the code to use the ThreadStaticSessionContext so that I could get a session without an HttpContext. This works fine for reads, but when I try to flush an update from the Task, I get the "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection." error. Normally what I see for this error has to do with using a column name twice in the mapping, but that doesn't seem to be the issue here, as I'm able to update that table if the session is associated with a request (and I looked and I'm not seeing any duplicates). It's only when the Task tries to flush that I get the exception.

Does anyone know why it would work fine from a request, but not from a call from a Task?

Could it be because the Task is asynchronous?

Call Stack:

> ```
> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32 index)
> at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
> at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
> at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
> at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
> at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
> ```

Session Generation:

```
internal static ISession CurrentSession {
  get {
    if(HasSession) return Initializer.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

    ISession session = Initializer.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    session.BeginTransaction();
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    return session;
  }
}

private static bool HasSession {
  get { return CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(Initializer.SessionFactory); }
}
```

Task that I want to access the database from:

```
    _maid = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
      while(true) {

        if(CleaningSession != null) CleaningSession(Instance, new CleaningSessionEventArgs { Session = UnitOfWorkProvider.CurrentSession });

        UnitOfWorkProvider.TransactionManager.Commit();
        await Task.Delay(AppSettings.TempPollingInterval, _paycheck.Token);
      }
      //I know this function never returns, I'm using the cancellation token for that
      // ReSharper disable once FunctionNeverReturns
    }, _paycheck.Token);

    _maid.GetAwaiter().OnCompleted(() => _maid.Dispose());
```

**Edit**: Quick clarification about some of the types above. CleaningSession is an event that is fired to run the various things that need to be done, and _paycheck is the CancellationTokenSource for the Task.

**Edit 2**: Oh yeah, and this is using NHibernate version 4.0.0.4000

**Edit 3**: I have since attempted this using a Timer, with the same results.

**Edit 4**: From what I can see of the source, it's doing a foreach loop on an IList. Questions pertaining to an IndexOutOfRangeException in a foreach loop tend to suggest a concurrency issue. I still don't see how that would be an issue, unless I misunderstand the purpose of ThreadStaticSessionContext.

**Edit 5**: I thought it might be because of requests bouncing around between threads, so I tried creating a new SessionContext that combines the logic of the WebSessionContext and ThreadStaticSessionContext. Still getting the issue, though...

**Edit 6**: It seems this has something to do with a listener I have set up to update some audit fields on entities just before they're saved. If I don't run it, the commit occurs properly. Would it be better to do this through an event than OnPreInsert, or use an interceptor instead?

Answer (score 1):

After muddling through, I found out exactly where the problem was. Basically, there was a query that was run to load the current user record called from inside of the PreUpdate event in my listener.

I came across two solutions to this. I could cache the user in memory, avoiding the query, but having possibly stale data (not that anything other than the id matters here). Alternatively, I could open a temporary stateless session and use that to look up the user in question.

Comment: My problem was very similar, but what helped me was realizing that I was querying the db to get the current user, but I should do that. Thanks for all!